# How to set max time to LocationManager in android?

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am working on geo-loaction applciation where I need to calculate user speed, to get user speed I used LocationManager for their current location after every 30second, for this I used following code.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000*30, 0, myLocationListener); //from NETWORK_PROVIDER

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000*30, 0, myLocationListener); //from GPS_PROVIDER
```

But my problem is I want location based on fix time interval here is 30second. Right now I get location after every 45second also vary. So if any know how I can set 'maxTime' to location manager then please let me know.

Also if any one know the location listener calling business logic based on time / distance also please let me know.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new introduced Fused Location Provider API

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;

public class Locations extends IntentService implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


public Locations() {
    super("Locations");
    Log.d("Locations", "Location service started... ");
}

private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private LocationClient locationClient;
private Location location;
private static final int INTERVAL = 1800000;
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 60000;

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    locationClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
 // do something on Location change.
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.w("Locations", "Location client connected...");

        // get last location
    location = locationClient.getLastLocation();
    Log.w("Locations", "Latitude : "+location.getLatitude() + "");
    Log.w("Locations", "Longitude : "+location.getLongitude() + "");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (locationClient.isConnected()) {
        locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
    }
    locationClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
}

}
```

Source https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: But is this API is able to work on NETWORK_PROVIDER, I mean what if GPS is OFF & NETWORK_PROVIDER is ON, then is GooglePlayServicesClient is able to give me location.

Comment: @AmolWadekar yes it will give, you just have too change the priority.